# Powering LEDs light

Tags: led, transformer, batteries

Why is it that if I connect rectified 9V (using a transformer and diode) my LEDs (about 50 pcs) doesn't get hot, but when I connect same 9V using a cell battery my LEDs get hot quicker and even brighter? Please I need a guide to understand and solve this problem.

The voltage after the diode is slightly high ~10.8V.

And for the battery it's exactly 9V.

Comment: Measure the voltage across the 9 V half-wave rectified supply and across the 9 V battery and edit these into your question.

Comment: How much time does a device getting half-wave rectified AC actually get any voltage? Also, did you include the resistor with the battery?

Comment: What brand and model multimeter are you using to measure the voltage, so that we can determine if you made the measurement with a "True RMS" meter or an average-responding type meter. (FWIW, average-responding meters are usually less expensive compared to True RMS meters.) Are you using a half-wave or full-wave bridge rectifier? Do you have a filter capacitor after the bridge?, and if so, what is the capacitance value and voltage rating for the capacitor? We can't offer good advice when a question does not provide enough specific information.

Answer (score 2):

> ... I connect rectified 9v (using a transformer and diode) ...

I'm assuming you are describing a half-wave rectified voltage source without a filter capacitor (a capacitor isn't mentioned in your question).

An AC signal whose RMS voltage is \$X\,V_{RMS}\$ delivers the same power **to an ideal resistive load** as a DC voltage \$X\,V_{DC}\$.  *(NB: This equality does not hold for reactive loads.)*

So what is the RMS voltage of a half-wave rectified signal? If we ignore the forward voltage drop across the rectifier diode, the RMS value of a half-wave rectified signal can be approximated as,

$$
V_{RMS} =  \sqrt{ \frac{1}{T} \int^{T/2}_{0} A^2\,\mathrm{sin}^2(\omega t)\,dt } = \frac{A}{2}
\qquad \qquad (1)
$$

where \$A\$ is the peak amplitude of the rectified sine wave. If we assume the voltage at the transformer secondary's winding is 9 VRMS, the peak voltage at the secondary winding is

$$
A = 9\,V_{RMS} \times \sqrt{2} \approx 12.7\,V_{pk}
\qquad \qquad (2)
$$

Plugging result (2) into (1) we see that **the half-wave rectifier power supply applies an RMS voltage of 6.35 V to the light-emitting diodes**. If one includes the forward voltage drop across the rectifier diode—which is present in the real circuit, then the RMS voltage is slightly less than 6.35 V.

Note that your 9 V power source supplies roughly 50 % more voltage to the LEDs compared to the rectified power supply, which is about 6 V:

$$
6\,V + (6\,V \times 50\,\%) = 6\,V + 3\,V = 9\,V
$$

so it's not surprising the LEDs are hotter and brighter when you use the 9 V battery compared to the rectified supply.

One final comment.  If you want to measure the RMS voltage of the half-wave rectified signal you must use a "True RMS" AC voltmeter (or perhaps an oscilloscope that has an RMS measurement function). **You cannot use an average-responding AC voltmeter to measure this signal because an average-responding AC meter is designed to measure pure sine wave signals ONLY.** If you attempt to measure any non-sinusoidal signal with an average-responding AC meter—e.g., you try to measure the pulsating DC of a rectified signal, the RMS value that's indicated on the average-responding meter will be incorrect.

Comment: Isn't the formula simplier? Like:  Vrms = 2/3 Vac. (Unless you want to know Vrms down to 1/100th of a volt)

Comment: @Fredled, equation (1) is a correct approximation for the RMS value of a half-wave rectified signal (the pulsed DC signal) that IS NOT smoothed by a filter capacitor. The OP makes no mention of a filter capacitor; he states the power supply consists of "a transformer and diode" (diode is singular: one diode) and no other components are mentioned. The RMS value for a full-wave rectified signal is approximately A/sqrt(2) or about 0.7A.